# How to set `class_weights` in the right way around?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

While setting the `class_weights` parameter in keras' model fit function as such:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, class_weight={0: 2.217857142857143, 1: 0.6455301455301455})
```

Im not sure which way to set the `class_weight` weights to the right class:

Is it `class_weight={0: 2.217857142857143, 1: 0.6455301455301455}` or `class_weight={0: 0.6455301455301455, 1: 2.217857142857143 }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have`class_weight={0: 2.217857142857143, 1: 0.6455301455301455}` This means

Treat every instance of class 1 as 0.6455301 instances of class 0" means that in your loss function you assign a lower value to these instances. Hence, the loss becomes a weighted average, where the weight of each sample is specified by class_weight and its corresponding class.

Now it's your choice (based on your problem) in what order you want to specify the weights.

Have a look at my [github project](https://github.com/AslanDevbrat/Decision-Tree-and-Random-Forest/blob/master/Decision_tree_and_Random_forest.ipynb) to get more information about class imbalance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Devbrat Anuragi, obviously I'd like class few samples to have weight 2.21785714285714, and the class with many samples to have weight 0.6455301455301455. How do I find out which of the classes belongs to class 0 and class 1 ?

Comment: This you can find by plotting a graph between no. of classes and frequency in each class. Then whoever class have larger frequency give to lower class weight and vice versa.

Comment: I am sure you are dealing with a class imbalance problem, Right?

Comment: Thanks, I see what you say. Yes, its a class-imbalance problem. I always find it hard to figure out what these high-level keras functions understand as to be class0 and class1 of an `y_train` array. I just tried both versions and one didn't make any sense, so now it works.

Comment: @MJimitater I am Glad, you got a good understanding.